# How to put this button next to my form field and not two lines below?

Tags: html, css, django

Im trying to learn django so Im making a website, but I dont know much of Html, css, or js. so I used a wesite builder to make a template, and Im just editing the codes it gave me.  This is the scenario Im trying to fix:

[Link to Problematic part's picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDcTh.png)

I want the yellow button to be next to the form field but I cant figure out how to get it there

this is the corresponding part from my html file:

```
<div class="u-align-left u-container-style u-layout-cell u-right-cell u-shape-rectangle u-size-30 u-size-xs-60 u-layout-cell-2" src="">
            <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-5" src="">
              <h2 class="u-align-center u-custom-font u-text u-text-default u-text-6">Add</h2>
              <p class="u-align-left u-custom-font u-heading-font u-text u-text-2">
                <form method='POST' class='post-form'>
                  {% csrf_token %} 
                  {{ forms.newcat.non_field_errors }}
                  <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ forms.newcat.name.errors }}
                    <label for="{{ forms.newcat.name.id_for_label }}">New Category Name </label>
                    {{ forms.newcat.name }}
                  </div>
                <button type='submit' name='addcategory' class="u-btn u-btn-round u-button-style u-hover-palette-3-light-2 u-palette-3-light-1 u-radius-50 u-btn-1">Add</button>
                </form>
              </p>
```

ps. I figured the issue is in the html parts, but if needed I can provide the css file too. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ways to get this done.

1. Inline Elements: Inline elements place new elements on the same line, so your label, input and button would all be on the same line.
2. Use CSS flex (example below)
   With flexbox, all elements on the container by default are added on the same axis.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
 }
```

```html
<form class="container">
  <label for="category">New Category Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="category">
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Comment: unfortunately the inline elements didnt make a change, and looks like the css already has flex in it

Answer (score 0):

I found it! For future people who might encounter the same problem:

The issue was an extra margin set for the button, which was preventing having it in the same line as others. and it's not in html, but in css. i went and got the button name mentioned in the button's html class (u-btn-1) and searched for it in my css file. sure enough it was there, and it had a margin of 96 px. I changed it to zero and voila! problem solved!